# send pdf file in xml message

Tags: java, xml, pdf

I want to send a pdf file within a xml message.
How do I do that in java? What data type do I use in the schema?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can transform the PDF file to Base64 Binary and wrap this into a container Element with type `xs:base64Binary`. For example you could use this schema definition to place your PDF file in the xml message.

```
<xs:complexType name="documentType">
 <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="mimetype" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="filename" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="content" type="xs:base64Binary" />
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

You can use `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` for this approach if you already have `commons-codec` in your project. It support use of chunked data and strings. For example:

```
// You can read in the PDF file with FileReader and get the bytes
// Please obey that this solution must be improved for large pdf files

Base64.encodeBase64(binaryData, true)
```

Comment: Thank you, if you liked my answer, consider accepting it. I'm glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use bytes array in some tag. For example:

```
<file>
  <name>Test.pdf</name>
  <content>here are the bytes of the file</content>
</file>
```

You can use JAXB to create the xml file automatically from the object.